# Why isn't \let\bf\relax working for bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, harvard-style

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{harvard}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@article{roth2007,
    title={Repugnance as a Constraint on Markets},
    author={Roth, Alvin E},
    journal={Journal of Economic Perspectives},
    volume={21},
    number={3},
    pages={37--58},
    year={2007}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\let\oldthebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand\thebibliography{\let\bf\relax\oldthebibliography}
\renewcommand\thebibliography{\let\em\relax\oldthebibliography}
\nocite{*}
%\setcitestyle{numbers}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

As I understand, the line `\renewcommand\thebibliography{\let\bf\relax\oldthebibliography}` should remove any bold numbering in the bibliography. But if you compile it, you'll see that the bold numbering is still there.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your patching of `\thebibliography` is wrong.  First you patch

```
\renewcommand\thebibliography{\let\bf\relax\oldthebibliography}
```

but then in the next line you do

```
\renewcommand\thebibliography{\let\em\relax\oldthebibliography}
```

which means that the previous redefinition of `\thebibliography` is going to be forgotten.  Better just locally redefine `\bf` and `\em`.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{harvard}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@article{roth2007,
    title={Repugnance as a Constraint on Markets},
    author={Roth, Alvin E},
    journal={Journal of Economic Perspectives},
    volume={21},
    number={3},
    pages={37--58},
    year={2007}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\nocite{*}
%\setcitestyle{numbers}

\begingroup
\renewcommand\bf{}
\renewcommand\em{}
\bibliography{mybib}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Just do both redefinitions together

```
\newcommand{\oldthebibliography}{}
\let\oldthebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand\thebibliography{\let\bf\relax\let\em\relax\oldthebibliography}
```

I recommend the seemingly useless top line: if some package you load does a similar trick, you'd be informed. Changing `old` into `OLD` or whatever will solve the problem.

It becomes less clumsy if you load `xpatch` and do

```
\usepackage{xpatch} % in the package loading part

\pretocmd{\thebibliography}{\let\bf\relax\let\em\relax}{}{}
```